# Suppressing multi-threading in used libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, cloud, python-multithreading

**EDIT**:
I ended up using a workaround to get the behaviour I wanted.
Disabling threading in the SSHTunnel as suggested in the accepted answer helped me pin down the problem.

---

I have a Python project that does a few things, mostly ETL.
It works fine when I run it locally, works fine when I stuff it into a docker container and run that locally, but deadlocks 80% in when I run that docker container in the cloud.

When I manually kill the process I get the error linked below, suggesting it is a threading issue. I'm not explicitly using threading anywhere in my code (and am no expert on the subject) and assume it's one of the libraries I'm using employing threading internally.

The idea I had to resolve this problem is to somehow suppress all threading that is happening in the function calls of the libraries I use.

Is there a catch-all way to do that in Python?

---

Steps of the program include moving PostGresQL data into Google BigQuery, then fetching data from BigQuery (including the new data), creating an Excel report out of that data and emailing it out.

Pandas' data frames are used for the internal representation and easy upload to GBQ using the to_gbq method.
sqlalchemy and sshtunnel are used to extract data from the Postgresql database.
Openpyxl is used for the Excel editing.

The whole thing takes less than a minute to run locally (either in- or outside of a docker container) and manually calling each of the steps separately on the server also works fine.
(The referenced cloud deployment is on a Google Cloud VM instance)

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any way to globally disable threading; at least not without breaking every piece of code that would use it.

Judging by the traceback, I assume you are using `SSHTunnelForwarder` from the [`sshtunnel`](https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/) package. This class takes a boolean argument [`threaded`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L658) with `True` as a default value.

Instantiating `SSHTunnelForwarder` with `threaded=False` will [disable the use](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L766-L767) of the [`_ThreadingForwardServer`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L413) in favor of the [`_ForwardServer`](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/master/sshtunnel.py#L371). This forward server is not using the [`socketserver.ThreadingMixIn`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ThreadingMixIn), which is where your block seems to be surfacing. So, that should fix your problem.

However, I'd be curious to know why your project blocks in the cloud context. Judging by the output in your screenshot, the whole thing seems to be almost complete and just hangs when shutting down the tunnel forwarder. The maintainers of the `sshtunnel` package surely made the use of threading a default for a reason. I'd want to stick to that default if in any way possible, but that's just me :)

Comment: Hmm, the plot thickens. Suppressing the threading in the SSHTunnelForwarder now lets me reproduce the behaviour locally. I figured I might not be cleanly exiting the server, but that doesn't appear to make a difference.

Comment: @Mara Anything the people here on SO can help with? In that case we might need a little more info.